# How to sum a series of values each time an index # changes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In the event I want to sum all the rows (column B), belonging to each index # (column A), how would I do this?  The amount of rows for each index # varies.
What formula (s) would I use in column C?

i.e.

```
A        B         C 

C15122  500.00   500.00 
C15150  58.66   
C15150  242.34  
C15150  156.08  
C15150  412.80  
C15150  425.46  
C15150  171.63  
C15150  46.11   
C15150  346.56  
C15150  34.53   
C15150  21.73   
C15150  525.83  
C15150  120.31  
C15150  61.13   
C15150  1,075.00     3,698.17
```

Comment: I'd look at sumif

Answer (score 0):

With your data starting in row 3 you can use in C3

```
=IF(A3<>A4,SUMIF(A:A,A3,B:B),"")
```

Copy down.